# IE11 Javascript: let [array] of object.entries "SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier" error

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, internet-explorer

In this block of code, I'm finding the "SCRIPT1010: Expected Identifier" Error on the first line in IE11.  This works perfectly in all other major browsers.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(CompanySettings)) {
 if (value == true) {    
   document.getElementById(key).removeAttribute("checked");
 }
 if (value == false) {
  document.getElementById(key).setAttribute("checked", "no");
 }
}
```

I'm assuming this is because it's an ES6 feature that's not available in IE, but I'm wondering if there's an plain old JS alternative I could use to the `let.. of..` that works in IE11.  I'm not really interested in adding an extra library just to get this block running.

Comment: es6 synatx is not supporting in IE

Comment: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/ie11-largely-doesnt-support-es6-shouldnt-this-be-mentioned-somewhere

Comment: Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and polyfills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and iterate the keys.

```
for (var key in CompanySettings) {
    if (CompanySettings[key]) { // assuming true or false values
        document.getElementById(key).removeAttribute("checked");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(key).setAttribute("checked", "no");
    }
}
```

Maybe you need another check for not own properties

```
for (var key in CompanySettings) {
    if (!CompanySettings.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    if (CompanySettings[key]) { // assuming true or false values
        document.getElementById(key).removeAttribute("checked");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(key).setAttribute("checked", "no");
    }
}
```